# checkboxes are not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to load data using ajax, but the checkboxes are not working

This is the html am trying to load using ajax

```
<div class="mt-checkbox-list" >
<?php foreach($product_offerings as $row){
$check ='';?>
<label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['categories'])){
        foreach(@$_GET['categories'] as $cat) {

            if ($row['id']==$cat) {
                $check = 'checked';
                break;
            }

        }
    }?>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" name="categories[]" <?php echo $check;?>>
    <?php echo $row['name']?>
</label>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

AJAX call:

```
$('#product_offering_id').change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var product_offering_id = $('#product_offering_id').val();
        if(product_offering_id != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"/organization/vendors/productOfferingsVendors",
                type:"POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                data:{product_offering_id:product_offering_id},
                success:function(json)
                {
                    if (json['success']) {
                        $('#categories').html(json['html']);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

am attaching a screenshot of the result am getting[image: checkboxes are not working]

Any help would appreciate, Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the HTML rather than an image of the page.

Comment: @NigelRen i have already included my html code

Comment: The HTML code that is generated?

Comment: <div class="mt-checkbox-list" >
<?php foreach($product_offerings as $row){
$check ='';?>
<label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline">

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['categories'])){
        foreach(@$_GET['categories'] as $cat) {

            if ($row['id']==$cat) {
                $check = 'checked';
                break;
            }

        }
    }?>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" name="categories[]" <?php echo $check;?>>
    <?php echo $row['name']?>
</label>
</div>
<?php }?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes are working now, it was the issue with the classes i used for checkbox, after removing it, it worked